# On horizontal scroll for a table, how can I have sticky th until reach the next th?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, horizontal-scrolling

I have a table with a horizontal scrollbar. I need to make the data of the first two rows sticky when horizontally scroll the table.
This is the table at the first place:

[image]

When I scroll I want "2016" and "Dec" to be displayed until I reach "2017" and "Jan", and the same for 2017 and Jan until I reach the next date.
This is the picture while scrolling:

[image]

and the picture when I reach the next date:

[image]

Please note that I don't want numbers to be sticky.
I already used [scrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) library for vertical scroll, but i'm not sure if it works in my situation.
Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sticky Table Headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405709/sticky-table-headers)

Comment: PLEASE read the question carefully before mark it as duplicate!
I'm not looking for a sticky header on usual scroll!

Comment: Have you solved this problem?? I'm also searching for this function. Thanks

Comment: @HokageSama You should be able to do this with `colspan="number"` to expand the width of the item, and then wrap the text in a `position:sticky;` element to move each item around within his `<td>`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion sir,
I tried this one but it doesn't work:

html snipet:
<tr>
        <th>#</th> 
        <th id="name">Name</th>
        <th colspan="14"> 
          <div class='accounts'>
            Accounts
          </div> 
        </th>
</tr>

CSS:

.accounts {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}

Comment: Sorry I can't it format right in the comment section.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using only css with `position: sticky`.

**Note:**

- Putting `.sticky` on both `th` and the text to have the effect like this:
  [image]
- If you don't want the text to be cut, just remove class sticky on `th`.

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
.table-wrapper {
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
td {
  min-width: 40px;
}
th {
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky" colspan="10">
          <span class="sticky">2016</span>
        </th>
        <th class="sticky" colspan="10">
           <span class="sticky">2017</span>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky" colspan="10">
          <span class="sticky">Dec</span>
        </th>
        <th class="sticky" colspan="10">
          <span class="sticky">Jan</span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```