# Bootstrap table header to stay fixed under navbar while I scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table of data and a navbar at the top of the page, I'd like the table header to scroll down with the navbar so that users can see the header fields such as "professor" and "gpa" while looking at the data.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

This is my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>VT Grade Distribution: Powered by Keller Han</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Optional Bootstrap theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-left"><img src="logo.png" style="max-width:80px; margin-top: -15px; margin-right: 10px"></a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="stats.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Courses</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="acis.html">Accounting and Information Systems</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="aero.html">Aerospace Engineering</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="bit.html">Business Information Technology</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="cs.html">Computer Science</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="ece.html">Electrical and Computer Engineering</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="finance.html">Finance</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="math.html">Math</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <table class="table table1 table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-      scale=1">
        <h1 class = "text-center display-k">Computer Science</h1>
      </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
      <th>Course ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Professor</th>
      <th>GPA</th>
      <th>A%</th>
      <th>B%</th>
      <th>C%</th>
      <th>D%</th>
      <th>F%</th>
      <th>Withdrawals</th>
      <th># of Classes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">1014</th>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">Intro Computational Thinking</th>
      <th>Bart</th>
      <td>3.50</td>
      <td>68.90</td>
      <td>20.80</td>
      <td>9.20</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>1.10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
```

Anyone have ideas on what I can do? If anything needs to be clarified let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sticky Table Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405709/sticky-table-headers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you are looking for is 'sticky table header'. Feed this to Google and you'll find a lot of solutions to this problem.

This guy made a nice solution you could try: https://css-tricks.com/examples/PersistantHeaders/

You could also use css position:sticky. This should look something like this:

```css
div {border: 1px solid blue;
padding: 10px;}

.stick {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br>

<div>
 
  <div class="stick">
    sticky
  </div>

  <br><br><br><br><br><br>
  end of container div
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

end of page
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class **navbar-fixed-top** to your *nav* tag.

You can inspect bootstrap's example for more information if you need it.

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/